# c++ allocation and destructor

Tags: c++, destructor, allocation

I got this class :

```
int x;
int y;
int **mat;

MyMatrix::MyMatrix(int a, int b)
    :x(a), y(b)
{
    int i ,j;
    mat = new int*[x];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
        mat[i] = new int[y];

    for (i = 0; i < x; ++i){
        for (j = 0; j < y; ++j){
            mat[i][j] = i + j;
        }
    }
}

MyMatrix& MyMatrix::add(MyMatrix m){
    int i, j;

    if (x != m.x || y != m.y) return *this;

    for (i = 0; i < x; ++i){
        for (j = 0; j < y; ++j){
            mat[i][j] += m.mat[i][j];
        }
    }

    return *this;
}

MyMatrix::~MyMatrix()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
        delete[] mat[i];

    delete mat;
}
```

and this is my main :

```
int main(){
    MyMatrix m(2, 3);
    MyMatrix m1(2, 3);

    m.add(m1);

    m.print();
}
```

All is working and prints me the right answer, but there is some allocation problem.
I'm working with debugger and see that the program goes twice to the destructor, on the second time the program crushes.

Please explain me whats the problem and why ?

Comment: Can you include the debugging attempt into the question?

Comment: The allocation of the two matrixes where fine. 
After the adding when I got to return it goes to destructor.
and on the end of main it goes to destructor again and crushes there

Comment: You probably haven't followed the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722). Combined with passing by value, not reference, to `add`, your class is a primed grenade, ready to explode at any time. I'd replace that pointer-juggling with `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` to sort out all the memory management for me.

Comment: Or, just use an `std::vector<int>` and do the offset math in the accessor. (This will require less memory and fewer levels of indirection.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes when you call `m.add` the parameter is passed by value so a new matrix is built at the entry of the method and then **destroyed** at the end. To eliminate this effect use a by-ref passing :

```
MyMatrix& MyMatrix::add(const MyMatrix &m){
...
}
```

This way the original one is passed into the function, but the `const` prevents you to modify it during the execution of the method.

Comment: Alternatively, the OP should follow the rule of 3/5.

Comment: It's working thanks. Can you explain more ? why is passing a copy make the program to crush?

Comment: @igor Because the object gets copied. The default copy constructor will copy the data members by value, so it copies the pointers. Suddenly you have two objects where `mat` points to the same array. When the copy is destructed the allocated array is deleted. Now you have the original object with a pointer to a deleted array. It should be clear why this is a problem. If you use `std::vector` instead of raw arrays this won't be a problem, as copying a vector means making a copy of its contents; the copy of the matrix object would have its own copy of the data.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious thing I see is that in your destructor you need to use `delete []` on mat. The other problem is that you need to supply a copy-constructor. I believe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27320023/1167230) is on to the biggest problem. When you pass by value and make a copy of `MyMatrix`, the default copy-constructor just copies all the member variables: `x`, `y`, and `mat`. This makes a copy of the `mat` *pointer*, not the data it points to. When that temporary `MyMatrix` is destroyed, the allocated data from `m1` is deleted because the temporary's `mat` is pointed to it. So when your program tries to destroy `m1`, it deletes a pointer that has already been deleted and you get a crash.

A copy constructor would look like this:

```
MyMatrix::MyMatrix(const MyMatrix& other) : x(other.x), y(other.y)
{
    mat = new int*[x];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
        mat[i] = new int[y];

    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < y; ++j){
            mat[i][j] = other.mat[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

A couple other tips. You might want to use `operator+=` instead of your `add` function so you can write code like:

```
m += m1;
```

Just change `MyMatrix& MyMatrix::add(MyMatrix m)` to `MyMatrix& MyMatrix::operator+=(const MyMatrix &m)`. Also, your allocation of memory is relatively inefficient. It will work, but there are better ways to implement a 2D matrix. If this is a learning exercise this is fine. If you really want to work with matrices in C++, I recommend looking into a library like [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/).